# Magento-2.0.7 Admin dashboard's links are not working after installing

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.0.7

I have installed magento-2.0.7

When I logging in to the **admin dashboard**, I **can't see any icon** of options(like **broken**). And they are not working.

Can anyone help me please on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution this way:

First, open the file `di.xml` from this location (below)

```
(Your Project Root) > app/etc/di.xml
```

Second, find this line on di.xml file:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

Replace that line with this line below:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy
```

There you can easily notice that just `Symlink`word needs to be replaced by `copy`

Hope it resolves your issue. :-)

Comment: That's my pleasure :-)